# Which CountHolder implementaion is thread safe?

Tags: java, comparative-review, thread-safety

1. Is it sufficient to only synchronize the `incrementCount`?
2. Is it possible for all other threads to get the updated value all the time?

```
public class CoounterHolder {

    private int i=0;

    public synchronized void incrementCount(){
        i++;
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return i;
    }

}
```

Or would declaring the `count` variable as volatile solve the problem?

```
public class ClassHolder2 {
    private volatile int i = 0;

    public synchronized void incrementCount() {
        i++;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Synchronized JLS: First, it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave. When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object.
    Second, when a synchronized method exits, it automatically establishes a happens-before relationship with any subsequent invocation of a synchronized method for the same object. This guarantees that changes to the state of the object are visible to all threads.

Comment: Please do not change the code in your question after receiving an answer. This invalidates the review you have already received. Please see [what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765) for more information.

Comment: Requirement is increment and get operation as separate.

Answer (score 1):

Both versions are thread-safe.

The first version will be incremented every time you call `incrementCount`. Although `getCount` will sometimes return a value 1 less than `i` is at the time, it is still thread-safe.

The second version is also thread-safe. The main difference is that `getCount` will read the correct value.

---

#### General review

> ```
> public class CoounterHolder {
> ```

There is a spelling error. Ensure you name your classes correctly, so it would look like `CounterHolder`.

> ```
> public class ClassHolder2 {
> ```

This name is inconsistent with your previous name of `CounterHolder`; it should probably be named `CounterHolder2`.

Also, what does `CounterHolder` mean? It seems to suggest that this class holds a counter, but it is best if I don't need to know what it contains. It would be better to name it `Counter`, or even `AtomicCounter` since we know it is thread-safe. Then, you could call `increment()` and `getValue()` on it.

Comment: 1. If you add synchronize on get method in that case if some other thread  is increasing the value then reader thread will wait to finish the write and then  read the value . 2. If another thread is reading the value then first thread will read the value then writer thread will wait to finish the read and then write. Thus synchronizing both method make sure reader and writer will be in sync and always have updated values.  If not using synchronize on getCount  then currently updating value might be miss.

Comment: @Damajikalunge Yes, you could do that too

Comment: I think it depends on client requirement while reading if he/she is interesting  in most updated value then  must synchronize the read also and write and read  operation should acquire the lock on same object.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I'm going to go ahead and say that neither one are thread-safe. The problem is the `getCount` method.

Really the `incrementCount` should return the value as well:

```
public synchronized int incrementCount(){
    i++;
    return i;
}
```

Now you can guarantee that when the counter is incremented, the count that you get is the actual value of the counter. Calling `getCount` at some point in the future will return some value that may have been modified multiple times between calls.

Comment: Requirement is increment and get are separate operation.

Comment: One more Question: In 2nd version if one thread is modifying the counter and at same time another thread is reading the counter (it is volatile) so does it returns after write completes (Happen Before Relationship) ?. If answer is yes then 2nd version is thread safe.

Comment: `volatile` is a message to the compiler (or runtime) to avoid caching the value and read it directly from memory. Reads and writes are not guaranteed to run in a certain order, it happens in whatever order the threads get to it.

Comment: okay in that case it is  necessary to make get also synchronize. Can I conclude that?